# Silverlight WCF calls work in IE but not in FF

Tags: wcf, silverlight, firefox

I'm having a WCF service deployed on one of my servers, and my Silverlight app on the other server. The problem I'm having is running it in Firefox 3.5. Opening in IE 6/7 works great, but when I open it in Firefox it loads the app, but on calling WCF service i get this:

*An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI 'http://10.1.1.20:87/MyService.svc'. This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent.*

(The connection works over VPN so don't worry about the IP address)

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem and after a lot of research I found that adding the following line of code into the constructor of my UserControl solved the problem:

```
bool registerResult = WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.BrowserHttp);
```

More information about the WebRequest member can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.registerprefix%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).